# why cant I get the content of the fields?

Tags: python, django

I'm building a website that displays recipes from cookbooks on a page.

Each page will consist of information stored in separate database tables:

Cookbook used | Recipe used | Ingredients used | Recipe steps to follow

Each recipe has steps to follow :

step 1 : Ingredient = Tomato | Instruction = Peel and Slice | Time = 3mins

Step 2: Ingrediant = Mozzerella | Instruction = Washs | Time = 2mins

Step 3: Ingrediant = Basil | Instruction = Wash and Prepare | Time = 4mins

The reason I want to separate the recipe steps from the actual recipe is that I want to be able to make the content in the instruction field searchable and add a detail view for each ingredient and show analytics on what instruction is most used and which is least used. I would also like to see in this detail ingredient view how many different recipes that the ingredient are used in.

Here is what I have so far

```
class cookbook(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)

class ingredient (models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)


class recipesteps(models.Model):
        ingredient = models.ForeignKey(ingredient,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        instructions = models.TextField()
        time =  models.IntegerField(default=0)

class recipe(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
        cookbook = models.ForeignKey(cookbook,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        ingredient_used = models.ManyToManyField(ingredient)
        recipe_steps = models.ForeignKey(recipesteps,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        def __str__(self):
               return 'name={}   cookbook={} `'.format(self.name,self.cookbook)
```

My question is am I missing something is there a way to store the recipe steps which are unique for the recipe in another database and assign them with an id that makes them unique to the specific recipe.

Am I making life hard on my self can someone please shed some light on resources I should be looking at?

## ** edit 1 **

my views.py file:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class RecipeDetailView(DetailView):
     model = recipe
     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super(RecipeDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['instructions'] = recipesteps.objects.filter(recipe=self.get_object())
    return context
```

my template.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2>{{ object.cookbook }}</h2>
  <h2> Recipe Name = {{ object.name }} </h2>
  <h2> Steps To Make:</h2>
  {{ instructions }} 
</body>
</html>
```

## **edit 2**

using the above code I have made real progress thank you so much to Paolo now I am almost there except on the template page it displays this where it should display only the content of the field

```
<QuerySet [<recipesteps: name=Tomato cookbook=Tomato Cookbook <recipesteps: name=Tomato cookbook=Tomato Cookbook>]>
```

this is showing the str(self) of my views.py and not the content of the fields am i doing something wrong with the self.get_object() command ?

Comment: I would say, shouldn't `recipesteps` model have a `recipe` foreign key instead of `recipe` having the `recipe_steps` FK? Cause with what you have right now you wouldn't know which `recipe` the `recipesteps` belong to.

Comment: When I do a foreign key in the recipesteps for recipe it declares an unknown variable

Comment: Yes, because you have to put the ```recipe``` before ```recipesteps```.

Comment: but then i get the same issue when I try to foreignkey into recipesteps from recipe if recipe is above recipesteps

Comment: would I need to make a new database recipe_recipesteps for each recipe?

Comment: Would like to correct you first, they are called ```models/model``` not ```databases/database```. There is a big difference between the two, I will put my answer below to try and explain it further.

Answer (score 0):

To expand my comment, here's what I'll do.

***models.py***

```
class cookbook(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)

class ingredient (models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)

class recipe(models.Model):
        cookbook = models.ForeignKey(cookbook,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        ingredient_used = models.ManyToManyField(ingredient)
        # Removed recipesteps FK

class recipesteps(models.Model):
        step_number = models.IntegerField() # To know which step comes first.
        ingredient = models.ForeignKey(ingredient,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        instructions = models.TextField()
        time =  models.IntegerField(default=0)
        recipe = models.ForeignKey(recipe,on_delete=models.CASCADE) #Added recipe FK
```

1. I would remove `recipesteps` **FK** from `recipe` model
2. Add a `recipe` **FK**  on the `recipesteps` model.
3. Maybe add a `steps_number` field in `recipesteps` to keep track which step comes first and not rely on `id`.

**Why?**

- You don't need `recipesteps` **FK** on `recipe` because you want to use `recipe` model to look for `recipesteps` not the other way around.

Also,

- Add a `step_number` field on `recipe_steps` because how would you know which step comes first then?  By `ID`? What if the user wants to change step **5** for example to step **1** and vice versa step **1** to step **strong text**?

Comment: thanks so much for your time Paolo to answer this for me I understand what you have said and will try to implement this... just trying to rap my head around how I can have one recipe template HTML file and show all the individual recipes wouldnt I need to make a new HTML template for each recipe and use a filter condition in the {{ recipesteps.filter }} to show fields specifically for that recipe?

Comment: You absolutely can, your basis for recipes would be the ```recipe``` model, and to show each step for that specific recipe you would have to filter ```recipesteps``` model using ```recipe``` object. ```steps = recipesteps.objects.filter(recipe=recipe)```.

Comment: again thank you so much for your time Paolo you have hopefully given me the answer I was looking for I will go and try thanks will let you know how I get on

Comment: ok sorry to keep this thread going but in the template with the cookbook and ingredient models as they only have one field I include them in the template like so `{{ object.cookbook }} and {{ object.ingredients }}` but when I try `{{ recipesteps.object.instruction }} ` nothing fills in the template ?

Comment: Where did you get ```object```? Have you tried just ```{{ recipesteps.object.instruction }}```?

Comment: This is in the a detail view class I am using for the recipe page...sorry am I missing something ?